# C++ Project Layout seems incorrect, compiler can't find implementation files

Tags: c++, compilation, include, project-management, structure

I'm writing a C++ Package for later use using Code::Blocks.
The project structure looks like this:

```
cNormal\
    cNormal.cdp
    src\
        main.cpp            # for testing purpose
        cnormal_defs.h      # important compiler definitions
        cnormal_storage.h   # includes all .h files from "./storage"
        storage\
            cnarray.h
            cnarray.cpp
            cnstack.h
            cnstack.cpp
    bin\
    obj\
```

The cnormal_storage.h:

```
// cnormal_storage.h
// *****************************************************************
// Includes all necessary headers for the cNormal storage subpackge.
//

#ifndef _cNORMAL_STORAGE_H_
#define _cNORMAL_STORAGE_H_

    #include "storage/cnarray.h"
    #include "storage/cnstack.h"

#endif // _cNORMAL_STORAGE_H_
```

To test the classes, i create a main-function in **main.cpp**.

```
// main.cpp
// *****************************************************************
// The main-file.
//
#include <iostream>
#include "cnormal_storage.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cnArry<int> arr(10);
    arr[9] = 999;
    arr[0] = 0;
    cout << arr[9] << endl;
    cout << arr.getLength();
}
```

But the compiler (gcc) gives me `undefined reference to ...` errors about `cnArray`.

Now, the `cnarray.cpp` includes `cnarray.h` (as it is the implementation file), so using
`#include "storage/cnarray.cpp"` works just fine.

It seems like the compiler can't find the implementation of `cnarray.h` which is located in `cnarray.cpp`.

I assume it's because of the folder-structure, can you tell me how I can fix this ?
Even adding `src\storage` to the include directives does **not** fix it. (And I also don't want to add it to the include-paths as this would be very unhandy for a package.)

Comment: `undefined reference` is a _linker_ error, not a compiler error.  `main.cpp` is compiling just fine, and finding the header appropriately.  You're not compiling the other two .cpp files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could spot the error now, `cnArray.h` declared a template class and template classes cannot be implmented in another file than they are declared, because the compiler must know about the implementation when compiling, not when linking.

I have found a workaround on the internet to `#include` the implementation **in** the headerfile, but exclude the implementation file from compiling.
This works just fine now.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the compilation command that you use?

Seems like you are compiling only main.cpp and not compiling (and thus linking) the other `.cpp` files.

Comment: I am using Code::Blocks, the *cnarray.cpp* is marked as "Compile" and "Link". I could provide the whole source, that wouldn't be a problem to me.

Comment: Btw, I see *cnarray.cpp* is compiled into `Debug\src\storage\cnarray.o`, may this cause the error, that it's not in the same directory as `main.o` ?

Comment: @NiklasR no, the error is that it `cnarray.o` does not get linked to `main.o`. Undefined reference means that the linker (the final step of compilation) does not find the symbols that `main.cpp` uses. Unfortunately, I don't know your editor. Try by yourself with the command line: `gcc main.cpp storage/.cpp -o main`